# Is there a way to get the number of occurrences of a column value and append as new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
    data = [
    [38338792, 'Display', 100.00, '2021-06-26'],
    [38338792, 'Display', 100.00, '2021-06-27'],
    [12455623, 'Display', 100.00, '2021-06-27'],
    [10107107890, 'Search', 35.00, '2021-06-27']
    ]
 
    # Create the pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['campaignId', 'channel', 'cost', 'date'])
```

I want to be able to group the data by month or channel or even month and channel and append a new column `campaignCount` so that the data looks as follows:

[image]

I can get the campaignCount I want using `groupBy` and `nunique` like this
`df.groupby('channel')['campaignId'].nunique()`. My question is how do I append the count as a new column ensuring that the count maps to the correct campaign. Thanks in advance. I did take a look [at this similar issue][2] and wasn't able to derive a solution as it is a bit different/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the count-Series with your main dataframe.

```
s = df.groupby('channel')['campaignId'].nunique() # this should have the channel values as index

df = df.merge(s.to_frame(name='campaignCount'), left_on='channel',right_index=True, how='left')
```

ah, judging from the other answer I might have misunderstood your question. Anyway I leave it on for now, in case this was what you where looking for.

Comment: This is very close! The only problem is `channel` isn't hard coded. So I would be grouping by multiple values and want to join on them as well in the merge method. In trying to do so I am trying to get past this error "ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"

Comment: do you mean that you actually group by more than one column? you would then simply merge on multiple columns/levels. Eg. `left_on=['channel','whateverelse'], right_index=True`.